# How to log out from google plus GPPSignIn?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-plus, logout

In my app I have a option to login to the app using google plus. Login is working fine. I am not able to logout from google+. When ever I click on login button it's not showing login page its redirecting to authentication dialog page.

My code is:

**To login**

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID= YES;

signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,nil];
signIn.delegate = self;
```

**To logout**

```
- (IBAction)Logout:(id)sender {
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
}
```

Comment: i'm too stuck with this issue..

Comment: What do you mean by "login page" vs "authentication page"?

Comment: Hi, i know this is an old post but it is still relevant. Please consider my answer:) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take GPPSignIn *signIn globally and add the following code in your Logout button action

```
[signIn signOut];
```

Comment: Also if its another view than loginViewController, set `signIn.delegate=self; ` then its calls `didDisconnectWithError` method and revokes the device token.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in) on `[GPPSignIn disconnect]`explicitly states

> "If the operation succeeds, the OAuth 2.0 token is also removed from keychain. The token is needed to disconnect so do not call signOut if disconnect is to be called."

@Revanth is correct, you only need to call signOut (Although the unfortunate naming of his variable makes the readability confusing).

Remember: signing out is different to disconnecting. Upon signing out you don't need to delete the users information. Google support users having multiple accounts so it could be that the user is simply signing out so they can sign in with a related account.

Disconnection on the other hand is destructive and you should remove all the users information from the server and on their next sign in they would have to grant your app permissions again.

Also, your App must include the ability to perform the following: ([See the rules](https://developers.google.com/+/policies#deletion_rules))

> Know if they are connected to a Google account, and if so to which account.
>
> Disconnect the application from their Google account(s).
>
> Sign out of your application.